# How does "sameModel" mean in Spark ML Pipeline, (Section: Example: Pipeline), from the docs?

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, scala, pipelines

I'm looking at the Spark ML docs in scala for Section: Example Pipeline https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-pipeline.html#example-pipeline.  From the example, the model is fit using a pipeline (val *model*), then the pipeline is saved to a directory.  The next line is

> val sameModel =
>   PipelineModel.load("/tmp/spark-logistic-regression-model")

I don't see how/where *sameModel* is being used.  I see *model* being used again on test data.  I would've expected the example to use *sameModel* to show how to invoke the loaded pipeline back into the process. Does *sameModel* automatically update *model*?

Any insight would be appreciated as I am interested in saving a pipeline following a fit then load it at a later point, but am having issues with:

1. Finding good examples saving & loading Spark ML pipelines, then invoking said loaded pipeline
2. Not fully understanding the examples I see online

Any assistance in clarifying what is going on and how to move forward would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that "sameModel" is just an example of loading the model back without any influence on "model" from the docs.